# It takes forever to arrive into SLComposeServiceViewController::awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, performance, responsiveness

when I select my share extension from the list of apps in photos app 
it takes quite a few seconds to arrive into SLComposeServiceViewController::awakeFromNib

Any ideas if this is curable and how to cure this?

Answer (score 1):

Not as big of an issue as I have feared:
this happens only when you start extension from Xcode.
untethered starts work in a timely fashion.
yet another lldb bug or whatever

Lest you read Xcode beta release notes: this was on machine that
did not have any "endpoints manager" running to ruin the xcode
interprocess communication act.